# Stanford Core NLP example code SemanticGraph exception

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have just tried out the Core NLP example code, included as *StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java* with the download. When trying to parse a chapter of a book, an exception is thrown from the Semantic Graph:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.removeEdge(SemanticGraph.java:122)
at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructure.expandPPConjunction(UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructure.java:553)
at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructure.expandPPConjunctions(UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructure.java:508)
at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructure.collapseDependencies(UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructure.java:807)
at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure.typedDependenciesCollapsed(GrammaticalStructure.java:877)
at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphFactory.makeFromTree(SemanticGraphFactory.java:188)
at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphFactory.generateCollapsedDependencies(SemanticGraphFactory.java:90)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotatorUtils.fillInParseAnnotations(ParserAnnotatorUtils.java:51)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.finishSentence(ParserAnnotator.java:266)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.doOneSentence(ParserAnnotator.java:245)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.SentenceAnnotator.annotate(SentenceAnnotator.java:96)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline.annotate(AnnotationPipeline.java:68)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:412)
at epubReader.Test.main(Test.java:68)
```

I have narrowed it down to one sentence being responsible, even when parsed alone:

```
"Generally speaking, he was a scout, and rarely stood at a watch nearer than the four hundred and fiftieth metre, and then only as a cordon commander."
```

Is there anything special about the syntax or semantics of the sentence that I am missing, causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the sentence is fine and this is unfortunately a bug in our dependency converter.

The part-of-speech tagger outputs a really weird POS sequence causing the parser to produce a completely wrong parse tree which leads to this exception in the constituency-to-dependency converter.

I fixed the bug in the converter but unless you clone the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP) and compile it yourself, this won't help you until the next release.

But you can still get a parse for this sentence either by disabling the POS tagger (see the [parser FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#corenlpdiff) for details on how to do this) or by using the [neural network dependency parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml).

Comment: Follow-up: We put a new release of v3.5.2 up on the website (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#History) which should no longer have this bug.